# how to set initial fetched data in input form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Hello I'm fetching data and then I want to display them as initial value in input form
but I'm getting undefined instead of values even when I see the data in console.log so the are fetched correctly
here is example of my code simplified

maybe I should use useEffect? because there is delay with fetching data and first there is nothing and later when data are received input is not refreshed?
I'm not sure how to use it
and my code is in typescript

````
export default function Form() {
 const name = data.name;
 console.log(name); //here I can see name is fetched
 const [company, setCompany] = useState<string>(`name: ${name}`); // name: undefined

  return (
        <form>
          <input
            value={company}
            onChange={(e) => setCompany(e.target.value)}
            label="Company"
          /> 
    ```
````

Comment: Where is `data` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

The following lifecycle methods will be called when state changes. You can use this method to update the value if something meaningful changed.

```
componentWillUpdate: function (object nextProps, object nextState) {
   this.setState({
      likesIncreasing: nextProps.name
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional component works this way - every render the whole function gets called, which means every render -

```
const name = data.namose;
console.log(name); 
const [company, setCompany] = useState<string>(`name: ${name}`);
```

those three lines are getting called, at the first times this runs it will set undefined to the variable `name`, it will print undefined and then create the state `company` and set it to undefined.
The next time it runs(or the next next time...) when data.name isn't undefined, it will set name to the actual data.
React hooks knows this isn't the first time the `useState` function has been called and because of that it won't set `company` initial state again, this is the expected behavior, so every render your state won't be reset to the initial state.

What I suggest you to do is, as you mentioned, fetch the data inside the component in a `useEffect` if this fits your demands, and then set the state inside the effect as well, don't send the `useEffect` function a dependencies array so it will act like `componentDidMount` in a class component and it will run only one time when the component is mounted the first time.